# Flutter : Error: Bad state: Not connected to an application

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

When using flutter hydrated_bloc in web in Firefox browser I get following error

> Error from backend:

> Error: Bad state: Not connected to an application.
>
> Stack Trace:
> #0      DevHandler._handleConnection. (package:dwds/src/handlers/dev_handler.dart:273:13)
> #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1407:47)
> #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1308:19)
> #3      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1217:7)
> #4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
> #5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
> #6      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
> #7      _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:218:10)
> #8      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
> #9      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1415:13)
> #10     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1308:19)
> #11     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1217:7)
> #12     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
> #13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
> #14     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:784:19)
> #15     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:658:7)
> #16     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:606:5)
> #17     new WebSocketImpl.fromSocket. (package:web_socket_channel/src/copy/web_socket_impl.dart:730:21)
> #18     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1407:47)
> #19     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1308:19)
> #20     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1217:7)
> #21     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
> #22     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
> #23     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:63:11)
> #24     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:13:11)
> #25     _WebSocketProtocolTransformer._messageFrameEnd (package:web_socket_channel/src/copy/web_socket_impl.dart:319:23)
> #26     _WebSocketProtocolTransformer.add (package:web_socket_channel/src/copy/web_socket_impl.dart:218:46)
> #27     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:111:24)
> #28     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1407:47)
> #29     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1308:19)
> #30     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1217:7)
> #31     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
> #32     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
> #33     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:784:19)
> #34     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:658:7)
> #35     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:606:5)
> #36     _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2447:41)
> #37     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1415:13)
> #38     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1308:19)
> #39     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1217:7)
> #40     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
> #41     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
> #42     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:784:19)
> #43     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:658:7)
> #44     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:606:5)
> #45     new _RawSocket. (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1936:33)
> #46     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1379:14)
> #47     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
> #48     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
> #49     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:123:13)
> #50     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:190:5)

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hydrated_bloc/hydrated_bloc.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(

      storageDirectory:
       kIsWeb
           ? HydratedStorage.webStorageDirectory
           :
      await getTemporaryDirectory(),
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class CounterCubit extends HydratedCubit<int> {
  CounterCubit() : super(0);
  void increment() {
      emit(state + 1);
    }
  @override
  int? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['data'] != null ) {
      return json['data'];
    }
    return 0;
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(int state) {
    return {'data': state};
  }
}


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final counterCubit = CounterCubit();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return 
      BlocBuilder<CounterCubit, int>(
        bloc: counterCubit,
        builder: (context, stateAsCounter) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$stateAsCounter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        // onPressed: () {},
        onPressed: () => counterCubit.increment(),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  },
);  }
}
```

with following dependencies

flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3
hydrated_bloc: ^9.1.3
path_provider: ^2.1.1